# describe all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ that have finite order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

describe all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ that have finite order. How many are there?

the only element in $\mathbb{Z}$ of finite order is $0$ it has order of 1

$\mathbb{Z}_6$ has 6 such elements and $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ has 10 such elements

the elements of finite order in the group will be of form

$(a, 0, b)\,\ \text{where} \,\,a \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}, b \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

and $6 \cdot 1 \cdot 10=60$ theres 60 such elements.

Answer (score 6):

The least common multiple of $6$, $1$, and $10$ is not $60$, but the answer is not given by the least common multiple, it is given by the product. The answer is $60$ because there are $60$ elements of the form $(x,0,y)$, which are all of the possible elements because an element of the direct product is of finite order if and only if each of its factors is.

Comment: yeah you are right, lcm(6,1,10) = 30, not sure why I was thinking that. thanks

Comment: @oliverjones No problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, but you should prove it.

Try proving the following lemma: *given the groups $G$ and $H$, an element $(g,h)\in G\times H$ has finite order if and only if both $g$ and $h$ have finite order.*

How many elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ have finite order? How many elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ have finite order?

Prove also that
$$
\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}
\cong
\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10})
$$
and you're done.